# Ionic 2 - Page reloaded after post request

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to send data to server for saving. Everything works fine, but for some reason the page is reloaded right after the post request. This is the message I see in the console before the page is reloaded: "Dev server logger closed".

Here is the promise I use:

```
save(data){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/postData', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe((res) => {
            resolve(res.json());
          });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I saved the data on a file on the ionic project folder, while using **ionic serve** makes a restart for every file change.